# Find out Shadow Prices via Apache Commons Simplex Solver

Tags: java, apache, apache-commons, simplex

i have a problem regarding [Simplex Solver](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/optim/linear/SimplexSolver.html) Library for Java. In my linear Optimization Problem i do not only need to know the optimal point value pair of the objective/target function. I also need access to other values of the Optimal Tableau.

---

I need to know the so called "Shadow prices" which are the values on the right side of the constraint-functions in the Optimal Tableau. I don´t find a way how to access them by using Simplex Solver.

---

I´m quite a novice and am desperatly hoping for some hints how to access them. Maybe there are other Java libraries or i am just not finding the way how to do it in SimplexSolver? Any Ideas?